# Solidity: How to verify Keccak-256 value?

Tags: solidity, keccak

I want to pass a Keccak-256 hashed value from the front-end, say a string "experiment". I store the value in Solidity, and, when passing the same value for the second time, a Solidity function needs to compare the values, and give true, if those values are identical.

I have been unsuccessful of comparing the values so far. I am trying this online tool: [Link](http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) , and then generate the value in Solidity via `keccak256('experiment')`. The results do not seem to match.

Any advice on how to achieve that?

Comment: For me, the results of hashing "experiment" with that tool and also with that line of code in Solidity are both `0x047dbe311ff69923d959629005cb27fb9d3c725f890180fb93365b03a25f0a58`.

Comment: That is utterly strange, as I'm not getting the similar result... Thanks, I will check the rest of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two values should be identical (they were when I tested). However, the tool you linked to doesn't append the "0x"  to the start of the hex value, whereas Solidity does. But they both represent the same hex value.

Answer (score 1):

You could have used web3's soliditySha3 function to get the equivalent of solidity's keccak256, as follows:

```
const frontEndHashed = web3.utils.soliditySha3({ type: 'string', value: "experiment" });

// or just this:

const frontEndHashed = web3.utils.soliditySha3("experiment");

// And if you send that to solidity it would match the following.

string value = "experiment";
bytes32 solidityHashed = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(value));
```

Then you would have frontEndHashed == solidityHashed.
In solidity keccak256 is just an alias for sha3.